# how to remove black field in wordpress woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, checkout, blank-line

As the title, my wordpress woocommerce checkout has black field. The field is not address or name, It just a blank and do not has any function. I have no idea how to remove it. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

[image: This is the blank fld picture.]

[image: the feild location in HTML]

[image: plugin (woocomerce checkout)]

Comment: Got a screenshot? Maybe some HTML that shows us the field in the definition of the page?!? Really hard to help with nothing more than what you’ve provided.

Comment: OK, I posted an HTML picture, the field I have removed from the plugin, so I have no idea why it is still in there. thank you.